# Is it possible to allocate the pinned memory from mex interface while using CUDA with MATLAB?

Tags: cuda, mex

I read [this pdf](http://www.systematics.co.il/mathworks/News/Pdf/2009/nvidia.pdf) and I have been using CUDA with mex for quite a while. I was wondering whether new generation GPU's such as Fermi and Kepler allow allocating pinned memory from MATLAB?

Comment: I am not sure why it wouldn't be possible. Did you even try to make it happen ?

Comment: Yes I did.As expected,I did not get the correct results.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you tried?  Did you use cudaHostAlloc instead of mxMalloc?  Did you try using mxMalloc followed by cudaHostRegister on the pointer returned from mxMalloc?

Comment: I think I messed up some memory management stuff when I last used the pinned memory feature. Today,I tried [this](http://codepad.org/J1aAI1Jz) and it worked fine in MATLAB.I was wondering if this is the correct way or something more is required.Maybe I need to explore more.

Comment: You are freeing datalf all the time, but are only creating it when input is double precision. This will cause failures independent of using cuda. Make datalf and datalf_gpu NULL initially. And before freeing a pointer make sure it is not NULL.

Comment: You also do not need datalf. You can do datalf_gpu[j] = (float)data1[j] without having any issues.

Comment: @noleptr did you get this resolved? If so, please post an answer so we can move this off the unanswered list.

Comment: @harrism...Updated answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [this](http://codepad.org/9wpuiNTB)  and it worked out fine. So I believe it is possible to allocate the pinned memory from mex interface while using CUDA with MATLAB.